# How to bind data in kendo grid after the kendo grid has been populated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

There's an event `dataBound` of kendo which is solving my purpose but the problem is that `dataBound` event will only fire once.

How can i run `dataBound` multiple times or any way around or is there any predefined event of kendo to do this?

Comment: Please include what's your purpose, how you integrated that event in your code and what you tried to do to fire it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can change the grid's data dynamically by calling the dataSource's `read` function :

```
yourGrid.dataSource.read({
    data: newGridData
});
```

You could also set a new dataSource for your grid by using the `setDataSource` function:

```
yourGrid.setDataSource(newDataSource);
```

I'm not sure how kendo grid will handle those call in the dataBound event.  If it's the case, you may have to use a `settimeout` to delay the loading of the data.  You also also note that reading new data or changing the dataSource will trigger another `dataBound` event so make sure you have implemented the right support to avoid infinite loop.